# Font-size on mobile Firefox different from mobile Chrome even though absolute size is set in body

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

**Problem**:  Font sizes are rendering inconsistently on mobile Firefox and Chrome (see image below). This only occurs on certain pages but not others. Specifically, the `em` scaling is rendered differently on the two mobile browsers. I'm using `@media` queries to target mobile viewports and performing `em` scaling. On desktop font-sizes on both browsers are identical.

**What I've Tried**: I suspect the font-sizes are cascading differently, but it's hard to tell because some pages render just fine. I've applied CSS Reset and absolute `px` font-size on the body and `em` in its children and as suggested by [answers of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899792/font-size-issues-comparing-chrome-and-firefox). I'm also using custom @fonts with declarations as follows:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'tf0r';
  src: url(../../client/typefaces/tf0r.eot); 
  src: url(../../client/typefaces/tf0r.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
       url(../../client/typefaces/tf0r.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(../../client/typefaces/tf0r.woff) format('woff'),
       url(../../client/typefaces/tf0r.ttf)  format('truetype'),
       url(../../client/typefaces/tf0r.svg#tf0r) format('svg');
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

[The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058509/different-font-size-just-for-firefox) has been most helpful so far. Setting `font-size-adjust: 1` property when applied to `body` does roughly scale up the pages that weren't rendering properly, but it also scales up other pages as well, making them obscenely large. I could target specific elements with this attribute, but I want to know if a more consistent solution could be found.

[image: comparison of two screenshots from different browsers]